# Showing "Exception: Parameter is not valid." while allocation of image from List<Bitmap>

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and this is my first question on StackoverFlow so please bear with formatting.
Q:While designing an application I want to transfer Bitmaps existed on **Frame1 (collection of pictureboxes) on Frame2(collection of pictureboxes but with some different arrangement)**. I am using **DragDrop** function to allot image to pictureboxes and creating the list of bitmap indexes to record in Frame1  and using the same in function **TransferImagesBetweenFrames_Updatepbindexlist()** designed for transfer of Bitmaps to allocate bitmaps to pictureboxes in Frame2.But while transferring I am getting an error :
**System.Argument.Exception :Parameter is not valid.**
in the following code:

```
   private void TransferImagesBetweenFrames_Updatepbindexlist()
    {          
        //try
        //{
            // Loop through each panel in panel_mid
            foreach (var panel in panel_mid.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList())
            {
                foreach (var pb in panel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList())
                {
                    //PictureBox pb = panel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault();
                    int pbindex = Convert.ToInt16(pb.Name);

                    if (pbindex <= dicomfileindexlist.Count)
                    {
                        int bitmapindex = dicomfileindexlist[pbindex - 1];
                        pb.Image = bitmap_list[bitmapindex];
                        pbindexlist.Add(pbindex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The error occurs at line   pb.Image = bitmap_list[bitmapindex]; and the Source is System.Drawing.

I have read other solutions but did not found applicable in my case. I have tried to clone the bitmaps to drop and  dispose **droppedImage ** in case of memory allotted issue that i guessed by reading other solutions but did not helped.

```
    private void sidepicturebox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox sidepicturebox = (PictureBox)sender;

        dragdrop = true;
        dragdrop_overlap = false;
        overlapindex=0;
        dragdrop_picturebox = new PictureBox();         
        dragdrop_picturebox = sidepicturebox;

        //--Get the dropped image
        var droppedImage = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

        //--Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
        Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, droppedImage.Width, droppedImage.Height);
        PixelFormat format = droppedImage.PixelFormat;
        Bitmap clonebitmap = droppedImage.Clone(cloneRect, format);

        if (sidepicturebox != null)
        {
            sidepicturebox.Image = null;
            droppedImage.Dispose();
        }

        //sidepicturebox.Image = clonebitmap;
        int pbindex = Convert.ToInt16(sidepicturebox.Name);
        sidepicturebox.Image = clonebitmap;
     
        //--------------------------------------------------



        if (dragdrop)
        { Update_pbindexlist(pbindexlist, pbindex);  }            
    }
```

The data in bitmaplist not shows any data as in image.Please help to overcome this error. Thanks:) [image]

Comment: Your picture boxes names are strings which are numbers "1", "2", "3", ......  starting at one.  You are converting the names to numbers and then subtracting one.  Then looking up the number in the list dicomfileindexlist.  The number is not a valid index number in the list.

Comment: pbindex minimum value is 1 so the minimum of [pbindex-1] can be 0 so it refers the first element in the bitmaplist.

Comment: What is max value of array?  What name is failing?

Comment: "dicomfileindexlist" is not array but a List<> so its length is not fixed. Not fixed "name" at which it is failing but failing randomly

Comment: So what?   You still cannot exceed the length of the object.

Comment: But as I said "dicomfileindexlist" length is not fixed so used list...also index is not an issue as I have checked it and not exceeding object length. The images of Frame1 is already alloted from same bitmap list. Just transferring bitmaps(0----(n-1)) to pictureboxes (1 to n).

Comment: What is the value of bitmapindex?  What is the length of bitmap_list?

Comment: "bitmap_list" length is 3..

Comment: And what is bitmapindex when you fail?

Comment: In first attempt it was 0 and in other one it was 1

Comment: I think pb is null.  You have a picture box that was never constructed.  You have an list of picture boxes and each picture box must be constructed.

Comment: Picturebox 0,1 in Frame1 were showing images so I guess those were constructed. Iam creating pictureboxes dynamically. Can the problem be due to some memory leakage kind in my program? Can I check it?

Comment: It is not the picture boxes.  It is the list bitmap_list[].  Are you deleting items from the bitmap_list[].  If so you are doing it wrong.